# How to extract particular Text from a given Alphanumeric Data in a cell in Excel

Tags: google-sheets

I have comments in a excel sheet , want to fetch particular data from that Alphanumeric cell

Example I have This data in a cell :   Order Id 186184 assigned to John.Doe on 15 May 2001

I want to fetch John.Doe in a new cell,

I have 10k records of same format so how can I fetch such kind of names every time

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `REGEXEXTRACT` here:

```
REGEXEXTRACT("Order Id 186184 assigned to John.Doe on 15 May 2001", "\w+\.\w+")
```

Comment: Thanks  for your help @Tim Biegeleisen, it worked for me

Comment: @Grig Then please mark the answer as accepted (Tick mark it) so that we can know it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple person to assign then you can try below formula.

```
=FILTER(SPLIT(A3," "),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",SPLIT(A3," "))))
```

[image]